# Project 2010 opens with blank screen

Tags: tools, ms-project-2010

I've run into a problem with my Microsoft Project 2010 file. Whenever I try and open it I just get a blank screen.

None of the alternative views (e.g. network diagram, resource sheet, tracking gantt, etc...) show anything. When I open the project information dialog boxes it appears to be more or less correct. When I open the 'Change Working Time' dialog box I can see that my resources are shown there but none of the standard resource views show anything.

Also, the title bar of the main window just shows "Microsoft Project" whereas normally it would also include the filename.

Some of my colleagues only use MP2007 and some still way back on MP2003. So it's quite possible that I've saved the file in MP2007 format somewhere along the way but I don't know for certain.

I've seen several posts on the web reporting similar behavior but so far I haven't seen any solutions.

I really don't want to redo all the work that went into this project file so I would appreciate any suggestions no matter how far fetched they might be.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what the root cause was but I managed to fix the problem by doing the following. Under the 'View' menu, I clicked on 'Arrange All'. ("Arrange All" is an icon in the "Window" section of the "View" ribbon). At that point the Gantt chart popped up and I once again had visibility to everything.

Comment: FYI, the "Arrange All" mentioned by Denis above is an icon in the 'Window' section of the View ribbon. Denis - thank you very much! Your solution worked! I've been having this problem for 6 months and you solved it. Thanks again!